# before broadcastreceiver open a layout

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i have the following code:

```
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent  = new Intent(context,
                                MyReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context,
        ALARM_REQUEST_CODE,
        intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,TIME.getTime().getTime(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 , pIntent);
```

after that, in broadcastreceiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent) {

}
```

but in class MyReceiver i can't open a new layout

Can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to start an Activity, either call `context.startActivity(...)` inside `onReceive()`, or make the pending intent be for an Activity instead of a broadcast by using `PendingIntent.getActivity(...)`

Comment: Thanks a lot i had to add myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);